# How to query the same column twice based on conditions of another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, report-builder2.0

I am a beginner with TSQL and was hoping to get some guidance on conditions with TSQL

Is there a way for the same SQL field to queried as different columns? My field name changes as the file moves from different statuses we have defined and I am attempting to use the associated timestamp from the status change to analyze some trends . For example the associated data for a file would look something like this:

```
<File_History
Loanstatusdescriptor= “Underwrite Assigned” Status.EventTime= “4/1/2017 12:05”>

<File_History
        Loanstatusdescriptor= “Closing Request Received” Status.EventTime= “4/3/2017 17:15”>
```

I have a report I am creating that is based on the statuses of certain files as they move through the workflow process.
Would the query look something like:

```
SELECT

LoanInfo.UnderwriterName

,File_History.Status.EventTime (IF loanstatusdescriptor= “Underwrite Assigned”) AS ‘Underwriter Assigned Date’

,File_History.Status.EventTime ( IF loanstatusdescriptor= “Closing Request Received”) AS ‘Closing Request Receieved Date’
```

….

The End Product Would Look something like

```
    Underwriter|Underwriter Assigned Date |Closing Request Received Date  
    Bobby Brown    4/1/2017                 4/3/2017
    Sally Jones    4/7/2017                 4/9/2017
    Chris Graff    4/6/2017                 4/17/2017
```

How would I write out the T-SQL Statements that would allow the columns to be created based on loan status?

Comment: can you show us you table schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `File_History_Status` is a table that can be joined to `LoanInfo`:

Using conditional aggregation with a known amount of columns:

```
select 
    li.UnderwriterName
  , [Underwriter_Assigned_Date] = max(case 
      when fhs.LoanStatusDescriptor = 'Underwriter Assigned' 
        then fhs.EventTime 
      end)
  , [Closing_Request_Received_Date] = max(case 
      when fhs.LoanStatusDescriptor = 'Closing Request Received' 
        then fhs.EventTime 
      end)
from LoanInfo li
  inner join File_History_Status fhs
    on li.LoanId = fhs.LoanId
group by li.UnderwriterName
```

Comment: Hi SqlZim, Thank you for the response.

When joining some other tables to the query, the aggregate MAX is preventing the other columns from being included within the query. Removing the aggregate function allows the query to run, but with several duplicate Nulls within the user-defined columns created. 

Should I add all those columns to the GROUP BY part of the query to allow the query to run?

Comment: @J.Mora Yes, you would include all columns that are not being aggregated in the `group by`.

Comment: Awesome Thanks for the help!